# Apple Pay with Stripe on Web - Error while Domain verification from stripe apple pay

Tags: visual-studio, web, stripe-payments, applepay, kentico-12

I need to add Apple Pay on the web using following link to integrate Apple Pay on my kentico website :
https://support.stripe.com/questions/enable-apple-pay-on-your-stripe-account

I have created a physical folder in the web root directly on the web server and copied the required files to this physical folder using FTP but it is giving  this error "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable." while verification of domain.

It is not accessing extensionless file "apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association" under ".well-know" folder.

[image: Screen Shot - 1]

[image: Screen Shot - 2]

[image: Screen Shot - 3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding extensionless file in folder. You need to allow this in your web.config file like below.

```
<system.webServer>
<staticContent>
<mimeMap fileExtension="." mimeType="text/xml" />
</staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this same issue. I checked the error log and discovered the hosting provider was blocking it w/ ModSecurity.  I contacted my hosting company, and they checked my account made some setting changes to allow it. It was resolved immediately, and now ApplePay is working perfectly.